# How to do default method handling in Scala

Tags: scala

I want to create a class that has an underlying map. I want to support operations such that the variables are resolved in the map. Normally we can have `person("height")` and have an apply method to resolve the key height in the map and return it.

I want to support fields to be resolved in this way. So `person.height` returns from the map. But the list of keys are not known before hand. So we cant enumerate all fields. Would it be possible to have a default handler of field resolution ?

Comment: As has been illustrated, this is possible with Scala's `Dynamic`. But I implore you to avoid this. You discard a tremendous deal of Scala's power when you side-step the type system.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably want dynamic type:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Dynamic

The SIP that lead to the addition of dynamic type in Scala 2.10: http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/type-dynamic.html

Here's a simple example that allow you to create objects with dynamic field resolution:

```
class MapBacked(initial: (String, Any)*) extends Dynamic {

  private val fields = mutable.HashMap[String, Any](initial: _*)

  // x.field translates to x.selectDynamic(field)
  def selectDynamic(field: String): Any = fields(field)

  // x.field = value translates to x.updateDynamic(field)(value)
  def updateDynamic(field: String)(arg: Any) = { fields(field) = arg }

}
```

Usage:

```
val x = new MapBacked("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2)
println(x.a) //prints 1
x.c = 42
println(x.c) //prints 42
```

You can also define dynamically resolved methods by defining an `applyDynamic` method.